# How to remove the link from org-capture templates

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I have the following org-mode capture template:

```
'(org-capture-templates (quote (("t" "Task" entry (file+headline "~/org/tasks.org" "Incoming") ""))))
```

The resulting capture buffer looks like this  (very vaguely, but you get the idea):

```
** 
   [[link to headline at point]]
```

This is what I want, except for the link. How do I avoid getting that? I'm not finding anything in the [documentation on template elements](http://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html) but I must be missing something?

Comment: You have shown a line of code that reads `(org-capture-templates (quote (("t" "Task" entry (file+headline "~/org/tasks.org" "Incoming") ""))))`, and you appear to be stating that it produces a capture buffer containing a link.  Where in that is example is a link being created?  Is it possible that somewhere else in your setup you are creating a link?  The doc-string for `org-capture-templates` talks about link creation with any of the following:  `%a`; `%l`; `%K`; `%:keyword`; and, `%^L`?  Do you have any of those somewhere in your setup that you are not showing in your question?

Comment: I can't find anything in my init related to those codes. I tried to see if my template behaves the same way on a clean init, but I can't get past his error:  `if: Target buffer ".notes" for file+headline should be in Org mode
user-error: Minibuffer window is not active`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation I linked to in my original question mentions that if no template string is specified "an appropriate default template will be used." Apparently that default template must be where the unwanted link was coming from.

I resolved the issue by adding a template string, `* %?`. So now my template customization looks like this:

`'(org-capture-templates (quote (("t" "Task" entry (file+headline "~/org/tasks.org" "Incoming") "* %?"))))`

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for that.